# c_hash claim in id_token and IdP MixUp mitigation

Tags: openid-connect

My understanding is that the c_hash claim in the id_token is used to prevent IdPMixUp attacks (http://openid.net/2016/07/16/preventing-mix-up-attacks-with-openid-connect/).

I have two doubts:

1. is the IdP MixUp relevant in the first place ? Some sources seem to believe it is not relevant (http://www.chrismitchell.net/Papers/dtimua.pdf),
2. can somebody explain why the c_hash validation would help to mitigate that attack ?